How to recreate Shadcn's command search menu by fetching data from my database?
I am trying to recreate the shadcn-ui command search menu, but this time using the data right from the database. At first, I thought it would be easy for me, but then it got a little complicated. I want to recreate the docsConfig (https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/blob/main/apps/www/config/docs.ts) by fetching the data from my database using Prisma ORM, instead of hard-coding it, then call my data in the command menu component (https://github.com/shadcn-ui/ui/blob/main/apps/www/components/command-menu.tsx). Let's use an example of a blogging app, and the posts are the items to be fetched from Prisma.
I would appreciate your help on this. Many thanks for considering my request.
